# Value Conversion issue: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int32_t' (aka 'int')

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, xcode5.1

I have upgraded my Xcode version from 5.0 to 5.1 & started occuring below error in GPUImage Library
 GPUImageVideoCamera.m:301:54: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int32_t' (aka 'int')

In below function on this line "connection.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, _frameRate);" error is occuring.

```
- (void)setFrameRate:(NSInteger)frameRate;
{

    _frameRate = frameRate;

    if (_frameRate > 0)
    {

        for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in videoOutput.connections)
        {

            if ([connection respondsToSelector:@selector(setVideoMinFrameDuration:)])

                connection.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, _frameRate);

            if ([connection respondsToSelector:@selector(setVideoMaxFrameDuration:)])

                connection.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, _frameRate);

        }
    }

    else

    {
        for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in videoOutput.connections)

        {
            if ([connection respondsToSelector:@selector(setVideoMinFrameDuration:)])

                connection.videoMinFrameDuration = kCMTimeInvalid; 
                                // This sets videoMinFrameDuration back to default

            if ([connection respondsToSelector:@selector(setVideoMaxFrameDuration:)])

                connection.videoMaxFrameDuration = kCMTimeInvalid; 
                                // This sets videoMaxFrameDuration back to default

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In Xcode 5.1 64 bit architectures are enabled by default. This should not be an error but just a warning. To get rid of the warning you can add explicit casts or update the Library.

Comment: Xcode treating it as an error

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar: Perhaps you have set the build setting "Treat warnings as errors" set to YES. - As said in above comment, just add an explicit cast, or change the type of _frameRate from NSInteger to int.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is related with `architecture`. If you open your existing project in Xcode 5.1, It's default arch setting is 64-bit architectures.

See this lines in [Xcode 5.1 release nots](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> Note: Be aware of the following architectures issues when opening your
>   existing projects in Xcode 5.1:

- When building for all architectures, remove any explicit
  architectures setting and use the default Standard Architectures
  setting. For projects that were previously opted-in using “Standard
  Architectures Including 64-Bit”, switch back to the “Standard
  architectures” setting.
- When opening an existing project for the first time, Xcode 5.1 may
  display a warning about the use of the Xcode 5.0 architectures
  setting. Selecting the warning provides a workflow to revise the
  setting.
- Projects not able to support 64-bit need to specifically set the
  architectures build setting to not include 64-bit.

You can see this line in [this apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW14).

> NSInteger changes size in 64-bit code. The NSInteger type is used
>   throughout Cocoa Touch; it is a 32-bit integer in the 32-bit runtime
>   and a 64-bit integer in the 64-bit runtime. So when receiving
>   information from a framework method that takes an NSInteger type, use
>   the NSInteger type to hold the result.

But `int is a 32-bit integer`, so only this arise this error. You can solve this problem by setting architecture to `standard architecture including 64-bit` or do simple type casting as below.

```
connection.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake((int64_t)1, (int32_t)_frameRate);
```

See CMTimeMake syntax.

```
CMTime CMTimeMake (
   int64_t value,
   int32_t timescale
);
```

Comment: Current settings are the same as you suggested standard architecture including 64-bit

Comment: Mani probably meant to *exclude* 64-bit from the architectures. But there is no need for this as this problem is easily solvable with an explicit cast or change of data types.

Comment: @MartinR Yes. You are right. I missed with my answer

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar then according to your setting, this problem also arised in Xcode 5 too. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, now i have typecasted and resolved the issue.
My concern behind asking Question is that if i am missing precision value by typecast then it will affect on functionality

Comment: No. In this case, It should not affect functionality.

Comment: @Mani: Unless I am mistaken, the correct cast would be `CMTimeMake(1, (int32_t)_frameRate)` .

Comment: @MartinR According to comment with Dattatray Deokar, his issue was resolved But your point is absolutely correct. Wait I'll update my answer.